# ReferenceError : products is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on online shop while I'm trying to fetch products from MongoDB its return products is not defined I'm using ejs as template engine.

```
<%- include('parts/header') %>
<%- include('parts/navbar') %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% for(let product of products) { %> 
        <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="<%= product.image%> " class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                      <a href="/product/<%= product._id%>"><%= product.name%>></a>
                      <p>Price: <%= product.price %> $</p>
                  </h5>
                  <form action="/cart" method="POST">
                     <input type="number" name="amount" class="from-control">
                     <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <% } %> 
    </div>
</div>
<%- include('parts/footer') %>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const homeRouter = require('./routes/home.route');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views') //default

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

app.use('/', homeRouter)
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server listen to port 3000')
})
```

products.model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DB_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/online-shop';

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    category: String
})

const Product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema)


exports.getAllProducts = () => {
    //connect to db
    //get products 
    //disconnect

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            mongoose.connect(DB_URL).then(() => {
                return Product.find({})
            }).then(products => {
                    mongoose.disconnect()
                    resolve(products)
                }).catch(err => reject(err))
            })
        
    
}
```

home.controller

```
const productsModel = require('../models/products.model')
exports.getHome = (req, res, next) => {
    //get products
    //render index.ejs
    productsModel.getAllProducts().then(products => {
        res.render('index', {
            products: products
        })
    })
}
```

the result

ReferenceError: D:\programming\OnlineShop\views\index.ejs:6
4|

```
5|     <div class="row">
```

> > 6|         <% for(let product of products) { %>

```
7|         <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">

8|             <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

9|                 <img src="<%= product.image%> " class="card-img-top">
```

products is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), :16:27)
at index (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
at tryHandleCache (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at D:\programming\OnlineShop\app.js:13:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\programming\OnlineShop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

Comment: I would try to debug on the home.controller 
just before res.renderer check what do you get in products

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because either your database is empty or your database is unable to send data. try using

```
<% if(products)  {%>

<% } %>
```

before the loop in index.js file.